# Find a columns of matrix $A$ which form a basis of columns space of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, machine-learning

We have a matrix $A$ whose rows are data records and whose columns are features. We would like to omit useless features such as zero or constant columns, duplicate columns, columns that are equal to other columns or columns that are linear combinations of other columns. I believe that the problem can be formulated in linear algebraic terms:

> Find columns of matrix $A$ that form a basis of the column space of matrix $A$.

Comment: Why not use Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Rodrigo de Azevedo: I do not want the columns to be transformed. I need to select subset of original columns.

Comment: Then do $B := A$ and perform Gaussian elimination on $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and well-known approach is "Gaussian-elimination". Make $A$ into a reduced row echelon form, and pick up columns which contain an element "leading 1". Then these form a basis for the column space of $A$; moreover, their original versions form a basis too.